# Rails generate model with 'has_many' association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I think it's a silly question, but I can't seem to find an answer.
Let's say I have two models, Car and Wheel. 
If I already have the Car generated, I can use the following command to make the Wheel have a 'belongs_to car' association.

```
rails g scaffold Wheel car:references
```

What if I already have the Wheel generated and I want to scaffold Car such that the Wheel still belongs to it. How can I achieve that? (Is it possible?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way around generating your Car scaffold and then generating a migration that adds its reference to the existing Wheel.

```
rails g scaffold Car with:attributes
rails g migration AddCarToWheels car:references
```

Rails has great [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) about migrations in general. I leave them here for reference :)

Comment: I think this feature would be nice, but most likely is not worth the complication as looking up model classes with namespaces for example would be really messy.

Comment: @max I agree. Doing it this way also keeps the migration files significant